# How to read JPEG file attributes with Java?

Tags: java, image

I want to read information from an image (jpg) which has some extra
information included from a digital camera like creation date, focus, flash
on off, ...
How can I get this information.

My first idea was.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(filePicture);
if (image().getPropertyNames() != null) {
    for (int j = 0; j < image().getPropertyNames().length; j++) {
        String key = image().getPropertyNames()[j];
        String value = (String) image().getProperty(key);
        System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
    }
}
```

But the getPropertyNames() returns null!

Comment: I need to read manufacturer, manufacturer's model name , spatial resolution and image type like that please help me thanks.

Comment: these are all EXIF data so yes, use Apache Commons Imaging

Comment: if we know some more info (do the images all have the same exif tags or do some have specific additional exif tags eg by canon, nikon ...) we can help with writing the right code but there are multiple tags named "*type", "resolution" (I don't know which one you need, I am not a photographer), ...

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/designerator/source/browse/trunk/org.designerator.exif/src/org/designerator/exif/test/ExifSSCCE.java?r=24 i used this one but it doesnt work :(

Comment: I meant that you use the exif viewer for getting the right needed exif tags. As already mentioned, use Apache Commons Imaging. Also I do not know which exif specification you use or need (2.2, 2.3?) and if these are custom tags by some manufacturers. The Commons Imaging library provides all methods for reading the needed tags. Please also take a look at the documentations of Apache Commons Imaging and the examples.

Answer (score 28):

Another simple option is to use [metadata-extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor):

```
Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(imagePath);
```

To iterate all values in the file:

```
for (Directory directory : metadata.getDirectories()) {
    for (Tag tag : directory.getTags()) {
        System.out.println(tag);
    }
}
```

You can also read specific values from specific directories:

```
// obtain the Exif SubIFD directory
ExifSubIFDDirectory directory 
    = metadata.getFirstDirectoryOfType(ExifSubIFDDirectory.class);

// query the datetime tag's value
Date date = directory.getDate(ExifSubIFDDirectory.TAG_DATETIME_ORIGINAL);
```

The library is available for Maven users too.

*(Full disclosure: I am the author of this library)*

Comment: I use Drew's library.  I HIGHLY recommend it.  It's extremely easy to use and has no shortcomings that I can see.

Comment: Shouldn't the sample you provided, `ExifSubIFDDirectory directory 
    = metadata.getDirectory(ExifSubIFDDirectory.class);` be `ExifSubIFDDirectory directory 
    = metadata.getFirstDirectoryOfType(ExifSubIFDDirectory.class);`?

Comment: Yes, thanks, updated now. The API changed a while ago, and that code was out of date.

Comment: does metadata-extractor allow for extraction of metadata from inputstream? or does it absolutely need an absolute path to an image

Comment: @Omnipresent, [`InputStream` is supported too](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/blob/master/Source/com/drew/imaging/ImageMetadataReader.java#L88).

Comment: Much better than `android.media.ExifInterface` which was unable to retrieve `focalLengthIn35mmFilm`

Comment: @OneWorld glad to hear you found it useful.

Answer (score 10):

I would suggest using http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/ which can read EXIF data and other formats (IPTC, XMP ...)

there are also some examples: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/sampleusage.html

What you need: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/imaging/trunk/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/imaging/examples/MetadataExample.java

```
/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 * contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 * this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 * The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 * (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 * the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.apache.commons.imaging.examples;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.imaging.ImageReadException;
import org.apache.commons.imaging.Imaging;
import org.apache.commons.imaging.common.ImageMetadata;
import org.apache.commons.imaging.common.ImageMetadata.ImageMetadataItem;
import org.apache.commons.imaging.common.RationalNumber;
import org.apache.commons.imaging.formats.jpeg.JpegImageMetadata;
import org.apache.commons.imaging.formats.tiff.TiffField;
import org.apache.commons.imaging.formats.tiff.TiffImageMetadata;
import org.apache.commons.imaging.formats.tiff.constants.ExifTagConstants;
import org.apache.commons.imaging.formats.tiff.constants.GpsTagConstants;
import org.apache.commons.imaging.formats.tiff.constants.TiffTagConstants;
import org.apache.commons.imaging.formats.tiff.taginfos.TagInfo;

public class MetadataExample {
    public static void metadataExample(final File file) throws ImageReadException,
            IOException {
        // get all metadata stored in EXIF format (ie. from JPEG or TIFF).
        final ImageMetadata metadata = Imaging.getMetadata(file);

        // System.out.println(metadata);

        if (metadata instanceof JpegImageMetadata) {
            final JpegImageMetadata jpegMetadata = (JpegImageMetadata) metadata;

            // Jpeg EXIF metadata is stored in a TIFF-based directory structure
            // and is identified with TIFF tags.
            // Here we look for the "x resolution" tag, but
            // we could just as easily search for any other tag.
            //
            // see the TiffConstants file for a list of TIFF tags.

            System.out.println("file: " + file.getPath());

            // print out various interesting EXIF tags.
            printTagValue(jpegMetadata, TiffTagConstants.TIFF_TAG_XRESOLUTION);
            printTagValue(jpegMetadata, TiffTagConstants.TIFF_TAG_DATE_TIME);
            printTagValue(jpegMetadata,
                    ExifTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_DATE_TIME_ORIGINAL);
            printTagValue(jpegMetadata, ExifTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_DATE_TIME_DIGITIZED);
            printTagValue(jpegMetadata, ExifTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_ISO);
            printTagValue(jpegMetadata,
                    ExifTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_SHUTTER_SPEED_VALUE);
            printTagValue(jpegMetadata,
                    ExifTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_APERTURE_VALUE);
            printTagValue(jpegMetadata,
                    ExifTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_BRIGHTNESS_VALUE);
            printTagValue(jpegMetadata,
                    GpsTagConstants.GPS_TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF);
            printTagValue(jpegMetadata, GpsTagConstants.GPS_TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
            printTagValue(jpegMetadata,
                    GpsTagConstants.GPS_TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF);
            printTagValue(jpegMetadata, GpsTagConstants.GPS_TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);

            System.out.println();

            // simple interface to GPS data
            final TiffImageMetadata exifMetadata = jpegMetadata.getExif();
            if (null != exifMetadata) {
                final TiffImageMetadata.GPSInfo gpsInfo = exifMetadata.getGPS();
                if (null != gpsInfo) {
                    final String gpsDescription = gpsInfo.toString();
                    final double longitude = gpsInfo.getLongitudeAsDegreesEast();
                    final double latitude = gpsInfo.getLatitudeAsDegreesNorth();

                    System.out.println("    " + "GPS Description: "
                            + gpsDescription);
                    System.out.println("    "
                            + "GPS Longitude (Degrees East): " + longitude);
                    System.out.println("    "
                            + "GPS Latitude (Degrees North): " + latitude);
                }
            }

            // more specific example of how to manually access GPS values
            final TiffField gpsLatitudeRefField = jpegMetadata
                    .findEXIFValueWithExactMatch(GpsTagConstants.GPS_TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF);
            final TiffField gpsLatitudeField = jpegMetadata
                    .findEXIFValueWithExactMatch(GpsTagConstants.GPS_TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
            final TiffField gpsLongitudeRefField = jpegMetadata
                    .findEXIFValueWithExactMatch(GpsTagConstants.GPS_TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF);
            final TiffField gpsLongitudeField = jpegMetadata
                    .findEXIFValueWithExactMatch(GpsTagConstants.GPS_TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);
            if (gpsLatitudeRefField != null && gpsLatitudeField != null
                    && gpsLongitudeRefField != null
                    && gpsLongitudeField != null) {
                // all of these values are strings.
                final String gpsLatitudeRef = (String) gpsLatitudeRefField.getValue();
                final RationalNumber gpsLatitude[] = (RationalNumber[]) (gpsLatitudeField
                        .getValue());
                final String gpsLongitudeRef = (String) gpsLongitudeRefField
                        .getValue();
                final RationalNumber gpsLongitude[] = (RationalNumber[]) gpsLongitudeField
                        .getValue();

                final RationalNumber gpsLatitudeDegrees = gpsLatitude[0];
                final RationalNumber gpsLatitudeMinutes = gpsLatitude[1];
                final RationalNumber gpsLatitudeSeconds = gpsLatitude[2];

                final RationalNumber gpsLongitudeDegrees = gpsLongitude[0];
                final RationalNumber gpsLongitudeMinutes = gpsLongitude[1];
                final RationalNumber gpsLongitudeSeconds = gpsLongitude[2];

                // This will format the gps info like so:
                //
                // gpsLatitude: 8 degrees, 40 minutes, 42.2 seconds S
                // gpsLongitude: 115 degrees, 26 minutes, 21.8 seconds E

                System.out.println("    " + "GPS Latitude: "
                        + gpsLatitudeDegrees.toDisplayString() + " degrees, "
                        + gpsLatitudeMinutes.toDisplayString() + " minutes, "
                        + gpsLatitudeSeconds.toDisplayString() + " seconds "
                        + gpsLatitudeRef);
                System.out.println("    " + "GPS Longitude: "
                        + gpsLongitudeDegrees.toDisplayString() + " degrees, "
                        + gpsLongitudeMinutes.toDisplayString() + " minutes, "
                        + gpsLongitudeSeconds.toDisplayString() + " seconds "
                        + gpsLongitudeRef);

            }

            System.out.println();

            final List<ImageMetadataItem> items = jpegMetadata.getItems();
            for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                final ImageMetadataItem item = items.get(i);
                System.out.println("    " + "item: " + item);
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static void printTagValue(final JpegImageMetadata jpegMetadata,
            final TagInfo tagInfo) {
        final TiffField field = jpegMetadata.findEXIFValueWithExactMatch(tagInfo);
        if (field == null) {
            System.out.println(tagInfo.name + ": " + "Not Found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println(tagInfo.name + ": "
                    + field.getValueDescription());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: please take a look at these resources for the needed tags: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format#Example http://www.exiv2.org/tags.html http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/privateifd/exif.html http://search.cpan.org/dist/Image-ExifTool/lib/Image/ExifTool/TagNames.pod

Comment: the best is you use some exif viewer tool to determine the right exif tags which you need to read (some camera manufacturers have additional custom exif tags)

Comment: I don't know which tags exactly you need. As already mentioned there are many tags with almost the same name. Maybe the ones which you need are these: http://pastebin.com/nLa03Qzs   also a great online tool to get the used exif tags in an image: http://regex.info/exif.cgi

Answer (score 3):

As others have suggested use http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging

Download the jar from: https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/org/apache/commons/commons-imaging/1.0-R1534292/

You can see all the tags here: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/sanselan/formats/tiff/constants/AllTagConstants.html

Here is how you would get the manufacturer and the model:

```
String fullFileName="D:/test/photos - orig/lg/20170204_143925.jpg";
File file = new File(fullFileName);

// get all metadata stored in EXIF format (ie. from JPEG or TIFF).
final IImageMetadata metadata = Imaging.getMetadata(file);

if (metadata instanceof JpegImageMetadata) {
    final JpegImageMetadata jpegMetadata = (JpegImageMetadata) metadata;

    String manufacturer = jpegMetadata.findEXIFValueWithExactMatch(TiffTagConstants.TIFF_TAG_MAKE).getStringValue();
    String model = jpegMetadata.findEXIFValueWithExactMatch(TiffTagConstants.TIFF_TAG_MODEL).getStringValue();
    System.out.println("Manufacturer: "+ manufacturer+", Model: " + model);
}
```

Comment: Link from Adobe does not work anymore use from Maven Repo https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-imaging