# How do I get the "details" of a file in Java

Tags: java, file, properties, attributes

This is my first time asking a question on SOF and am stuck on how to get the details of a certain file. I am talking about this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYEBR.png

How would I get the Title, Tags, Comments, etc and be able to manipulate them?

Thanks.

edit: Sorry for the lack of quality in my question, I'll try again: (Please take into consideration that I am a nooby in terms of programming experience).

My first attempt attempt was to look at the File class and see if it had any methods which would find the "details" of a file. This wasn't really helpful.

Second attempt: I tried to do more research and found the Properties class:

```
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    File y = new File("C:/Users/someImage.jpg");
    System.out.println(y.exists()); //check if the file exists

    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(y);
    prop.load(in);

    String property = prop.getProperty("Title");
    System.out.println(property); //try to see how it works
```

which gave me an output of:

```
true
null
```

I am still doing some more research on how I can get the "details" of any said file, but some guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You should post your attempt.

Comment: Welcome @EvanYounan. Please take two minutes to read these links and improve your question. http://stackoverflow.com/tour and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Cheers!

Comment: Looks like this forum discussion is about the same question: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/172608/Getting-file-details-using-java (copied from answer by low-rep user @FlorenceCG - this should be a comment, not an answer)

Comment: @R O M A N I A @Tom Is that a little better?

Comment: Maybe this can help https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor

Comment: It appears you are trying to get info from a graphics file from the posted picture. But your question is somewhat vague, since the “properties” or info about the file read will depend on what kind of file it is. Example you show details tab of a jpg file, but a simple text file is not going to have properties like image dimensions. So the info really depends on what your looking at.

Comment: @EvanYounan: that's much better! Welcome to SO! :)

Comment: @JohnG Well any type of image file would suffice. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224328/how-to-read-jpeg-file-attributes-with-java) where `metadata-extractor` library was recommended.

I did a test myself and it seems to work very well.

This example was extracted from their [Github source code](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor).

Try to adapt to your needs:

```
import com.drew.imaging.ImageMetadataReader;
import com.drew.imaging.ImageProcessingException;
import com.drew.metadata.Directory;
import com.drew.metadata.Metadata;
import com.drew.metadata.Tag;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FilePropertiesTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("/Users/name/folder/test.png");

        try {
            Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(file);
            print(metadata);
        } catch (ImageProcessingException e) {
            // handle exception
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle exception
        }
    }

    private static void print(Metadata metadata) {
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------");

        for (Directory directory : metadata.getDirectories()) {
            // Each Directory stores values in Tag objects
            for (Tag tag : directory.getTags()) {
                System.out.println(tag);
            }

            // Each Directory may also contain error messages
            if (directory.hasErrors()) {
                for (String error : directory.getErrors()) {
                    System.err.println("ERROR: " + error);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tested it using JPG and PNG files.
The outputs written by `print` method are similar, like this:

```
[PNG-IHDR] Image Width - 640
[PNG-IHDR] Image Height - 960
[PNG-IHDR] Bits Per Sample - 8
//...
[PNG-iCCP] ICC Profile Name - ICC Profile
//...
[File] File Name - test.png
[File] File Size - 1223033 bytes
[File] File Modified Date - Sun Oct 16 11:24:12 +11:00 2016
```

I don't know if it returns all the properties you need, but it's a good try.

Good luck and I hope it's somehow helpful.