# itext 7.1 how to check if image is rotated

Tags: itext, itext7

in itext 7.1, I am adding an image to a pdf document with following code :

```
Document document = new Document(writerPdf);   //make a new document object
ImageData imgData = ImageDataFactory.create(imageBytes);
Image image = new Image(imgData);
document.add(image);
```

This works fine for most images but I have come across an image that seems normal on desktop but when adding to pdf it is rotated by -90 .

```
imgData.getRotation() gives 0 as output
```

My question is :

1. how to check if image has any rotation set.
2. imgData.setRotation(90) does not seem to work for me. How to rotate .
   Thanks.

Comment: Are you adding images to different PDFs, or are you creating PDFs to add images to? It could be possible your source PDF's page is rotated by -90 degrees.

Comment: @JonReilly I am making a new pdf. issue is with a particular image. other images work fine.

Comment: *"imgData.setRotation(90) does not seem to work for me"* - What does that mean? does it not rotate at all? Does it rotate in the wrong way?

Comment: @mkl yes it does not rotate the problem image. Main question is how to detect if image will be rotated in itext pdf.

Comment: *"Main question is how to detect if image will be rotated in itext"* - It won't. But sometimes it should. If you take a photo with your camera holding it at a 90° angle, the resulting image will be at a 90° angle. But cameras with a sensor for the orientation they are held in usually add an information to the image that it should be displayed rotated by the sensed angle. Usually image viewers do display the image rotated accordingly (which is why it *"seems normal on desktop"*) but iText does not (which is why it does not appear the correct side up in the PDF).

Comment: @mkl thanks for the detailed explanation. " it should be displayed rotated by the sensed angle" , if this is in metadata maybe iText can allow to read this information and rotate image accordingly. Not sure if this is currently possible.

Comment: This question was also asked on the iText Jira. You will get an answer there. Remember, when you have a support contract, you can always contact iText directly and have a guaranteed reply. Stack Overflow is not guaranteed for correctness or response time, and you may not even get a reply from an iText employee but from someone else who volunteers to help you.

Comment: As far as I can see the `Rotation` property of `ImageData` currently is only extracted for TIFF files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iText 7 unfortunately in general does not read (or at least not provide) that information, the `Rotation` property of `ImageData` currently is only extracted for TIFF files.

If the image has EXIF metadata and the orientation is properly contained in them, though, you can try and read those metadata using an appropriate library and use that orientation for inserting the image using iText.

One such library is [Drew Noakes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24874/drew-noakes)'s [metadata-extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor), cf. e.g. [his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28418194/1729265). It can be retrieved via maven using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.drewnoakes</groupId>
    <artifactId>metadata-extractor</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

With that dependency available, you can go ahead and try:

```
Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes));
ExifIFD0Directory exifIFD0Directory = metadata.getFirstDirectoryOfType(ExifIFD0Directory.class);
int orientation = exifIFD0Directory.getInt(ExifIFD0Directory.TAG_ORIENTATION);

double angle = 0;
switch (orientation)
{
case 1:
case 2:
    angle = 0; break;
case 3:
case 4:
    angle = Math.PI; break;
case 5:
case 6:
    angle = - Math.PI / 2; break;
case 7:
case 8:
    angle = Math.PI / 2; break;
}

Document document = new Document(writerPdf);
ImageData imgData = ImageDataFactory.create(imageBytes);
Image image = new Image(imgData);
image.setRotationAngle(angle);
document.add(image);
```

*(from the [RecognizeRotatedImage](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/content/RecognizeRotatedImage.java#L45) test `testOskar`)*

(For values 2, 4, 5, and 7 one actually also needs to flip the image; for more backgrounds look e.g. [here](https://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2012/07/28/exif-orientation-handling-is-a-ghetto/).)

To be safe, consider wrapping the EXIF related code parts in an appropriate `try-catch` envelope.

Answer (score 2):

for anyone else facing this issue , this is response from iText team 
You will have to write your own logic for this. iText has no way of detecting whether or not your image has been rotated.
If your working with portrait images for example, you could create a method that compares the width of the image to its height and rotates it accordingly. However this is out of scope for iText.

Answer (score 0):

Before you add image, you should check image with uri of image. This function will auto rotate the image for you:

```
 public static boolean rotatedImage(Uri uri) throws IOException {
    InputStream input = MyApplication.getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    BitmapFactory.Options onlyBoundsOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    onlyBoundsOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    onlyBoundsOptions.inDither = true; // optional
    onlyBoundsOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; // optional
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, onlyBoundsOptions);
    input.close();

    if ((onlyBoundsOptions.outWidth == -1) || (onlyBoundsOptions.outHeight == -1)) {
        return false;
    }

    int originalSize = (onlyBoundsOptions.outHeight > onlyBoundsOptions.outWidth) ? onlyBoundsOptions.outHeight : onlyBoundsOptions.outWidth;
    double ratio = (originalSize > THUMBNAIL_SIZE) ? (originalSize / (double) THUMBNAIL_SIZE) : 1.0;

    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = getPowerOfTwoForSampleRatio(ratio);
    bitmapOptions.inDither = true; // optional
    bitmapOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

    input = MyApplication.getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, bitmapOptions);
    input.close();

    // Rotate the bitmap if the image is in landscape orientation
    ExifInterface exif = null;
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            exif = new ExifInterface(MyApplication.getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
        } else {
            exif = new ExifInterface(uri.getPath());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
    int rotationDegrees = 0;

    switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            rotationDegrees = 90;
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            rotationDegrees = 180;
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            rotationDegrees = 270;
            break;
    }

    if (rotationDegrees != 0) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(rotationDegrees);

        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        if (rotatedBitmap != null && !rotatedBitmap.equals(bitmap)) {
            bitmap.recycle(); // Release the original bitmap
            bitmap = rotatedBitmap; // Set the rotated bitmap as the new bitmap
        }
    }

    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(new File(uri.getPath())));

    return true;

}
```

Comment: You decode the bitmap from its source format, rotate it, and re-encode it as JPG. This is a lossy process. Nonetheless, it can be helpful to get a copy of the image with no further rotation requirements.

Comment: Thanks for reply me. I was researched then i realized the image was rotated by Camera but we cant see it. Only when we use the image in code. It will rotated. So i think two directions: 1. Fix it before add to itext, 2. Fix it when take a picture in custom cameraX.