# What might be the reason for Image image = Image.getInstance( returning rotated image?

Tags: java, itext

URL url = url of an image;
Image img = Image.getInstance(url);

Used this code for Java iText pdf.

But the img Im getting is rotated.
What might be the reason?

I tried byte code conversion and http methods for accessing the image by url. In all ways it getting rotated, but the actual image is straight.

Comment: "but the actual image is straight" are you sure about that? I mean, are you sure it's not the software you're using to view the image that rotates it for you using EXIF data or something similar?

Comment: I'd also assume that the original image _is_ sideways as seen in the PDF while image viewers usually use EXIF data to rotate it to an upright position. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48568754/1729265) shows a way to use the EXIF data in the context of iText 7. You may be able to port that for iText 5 or earlier which you appear to use